# Variable suddenly changes for no apparent reason when function is called

Tags: c++

The variable indexMax changes to 3 regardless of the original value of indexMax, for no apparent reason when the function fibonacciGenerator is called.

And when I try to get the size of the array it outputs 2.

```
int fibonacciGeneator(int arr[], int n_1, int n_2, int counter, int index){
    int x = counter;
    x--;
    int n = n_1+n_2;

    if(x > 0){
        arr[index] = n;
        return fibonacciGeneator(arr,n,n_1,x,index+1);
    }
    else{
        return arr[index] = n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numArr[] = {1,1};
    int indexMax = 5;

    cout << "Index: " << indexMax << endl;              // The variable indexMax changes value for no apparent reason.
    fibonacciGeneator(numArr,1,1,indexMax,2);
    cout << "Index: " << indexMax << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < indexMax+2; i++){
        cout << numArr[i] << endl;
    }

    int arrSize = sizeof(numArr)/sizeof(numArr[0]); // Outputs 2 which might be due to the original array length of 2.
    cout << arrSize;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're overrunning a 2-element array (which contains only the accessible indices 0 and 1), so your program exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: You can diagnose this kind of bug with valgrind or your compiler's address sanitizer, but this example is very straightforward. Just look at the indices you access in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int numArr[] = {1,1};` creates an array of two integers (it's type is literally `int[2]`) and it is absolutely impossible to resize it. Writing to index [2] is writing past the end of the array, which is illegal and undefined behavior. Anything can happen. It might overwrite variables, it might work, it might crash, it might erase your personal files, and it might switch which of these it does each time it runs.

Prefer to use `std::vector<int>`, which is resizable, via the `resize(...)` method. You'll also want to pass this by reference, so that each function call modifies the same instance, instead of making copies and each modifying their own local copy.

Comment: And if course even with `std::vector` it won't automatically resize just because you wrote to an index outside is current size. You have to specifically request it to change size with the `resize()` method.

Comment: @ArthurTacca: Yeah, in this case that's probably worth calling out explicitly. Done.